# Async process in Spring

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I have the following in my Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public String index() {
    System.out.println("Parent: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    task();
    return "Hello";
}

@Async("executorWithPoolSizeRange")
public void task() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Child Process: "
                + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("................................. started");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("................................. done");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have also added

```
    <task:annotation-driven executor="executorWithPoolSizeRange" />
<task:executor id="executorWithPoolSizeRange" pool-size="5-25"
    queue-capacity="100"></task:executor>
```

to my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml. Am I still missing out something? The process is not working asynchronously. The controller takes 5 secs to return response and both the output of thread names is same. That is its the same thread. *(I know I shouldn't rely on thread name since its automatically set)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason your method invocation is not asynchronous is because you are invoking the method within the same component. The async proxy for your method that spring creates is only seen by other services making an 'external' call to your task() method.

Try moving your task() method out of the controller and into a service. Then when you invoke the method from your controller you should be invoking the 'async' version.

Comment: or saying it in a better way is that we should call the object created by spring and not a direct instance. thanks for your answer. wondering how i missed it :)

Comment: No problem. I think it's one of the big 'gotchas' with the @Async annotation that everyone seems to run into :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) yet.It will ease your asynchronous task and is based on producer consumer approach , where consumer will do your task asynchronously. 
See this [link](http://www.journaldev.com/1034/java-blockingqueue-example-implementing-producer-consumer-problem) for more info.